# how to filter php array list and get return as array

Tags: php

this is my array in `print_r()`

```
Array([0]=> stdCLass Object ([name] =>john 
                             [surname] =>future
                             [group] =>one1
                            ) 
      [1]=> stdCLass Object ([name] =>chris 
                             [surname] =>past
                             [group] =>two2
                            ) 
)
```

what I want to do is search this array by group. example. tell it
`group ="one1"`

and my return would be `name=john` , `surname = future`

I don't know how to attempt this.

Comment: I dnt know where to begin. thats the problem.  the only array filter array examples I saw was one that returns odd number or even numbers .

Comment: Do you want the result back as a string or an array or an object?

Comment: as a normal php array. if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the array is called `$groups`

To return an array containing the name and surname

```
function get_name_from_groups($groups, $group_name)
{

    foreach ( $groups as $group ) {
        if ( $group->group == $group_name ) {
           return array( 'name' => $group->name, 
                         'surname' => $group->surname
                       );
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$var = get_name_from_groups($groups, 'one1');
if ( $var === false ) {
    echo 'The group one1 does not exist';
    exit;
}
echo 'Name = ' . $var['name'];
echo 'Surname = ' . $var['surname'];
```

To return an object containing the name and surname

```
function get_name_from_groups($groups, $group_name)
{

    foreach ( $groups as $group ) {
        if ( $group->group == $group_name ) {
           $ret = new stdClass();
           $ret->name    = $group->name;
           $ret->surname = $group->surname;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$var = get_name_from_groups($groups, 'one1');
if ( $var === false ) {
    echo 'The group one1 does not exist';
    exit;
}
echo 'Name = ' . $var->name;
echo 'Surname = ' . $var->surname;
```

Comment: so in order to excute this I just call the function right

Comment: Yup just like  i showed you, ah, fixed the missing `}` to complete the function. Sorry, refresh page to see amended code, and the `return false` in the wrong place, sorry again

Comment: okay thanx I saw that.  im getting an error.. am I calling the function correct. when.I say get_name_from_groups(group,one1);

Comment: nevermind.. it works like a bomb...thanks alot kepp up.the.good work.. basically inside when I call the function I should just pass the array name and the name of the group I want to search.. awesome